# matrix cells of the same row and column

Tags: kdb

Is there a more efficient/idiomatic way to retrieve cells of a matrix that are on the same row and column as the given cell?

```
q) f:{except[;y] x[y div n;],x[;y mod n:count first x]}
q) show A:s#til prd s:2 3
0 1 2
3 4 5
q) f[A;4]
3 5 1
q) f[A;2]
0 1 5
```

Comment: are we assuming that each element of the matrix has a unique value?

Comment: yes, and more narrowly, each item is a cell index, encoding the position in the matrix

Answer (score 4):

```
g:{
  s:count each 1 first\x; // shape
  rc:s vs y; // y as row-column
  on:rc+/:{x,reverse each x} -1 1,'0; // orthogonal neighbours of rc
  nn:on where all flip[on]within'0,'s-1; // near neighbours: eliminate out of range
  x ./:nn }
```

```
q)A:2 3#til prd 2 3
q)g[A;4]
1 3 5
q)g[A;2]
5 1
```

If `A` contains only the indices of its raze (`raze A`) then we need only its shape, and `g` can return the indexes of the orthogonal neighbours of `y`.

```
h:{[s;y]
  rc:s vs y; // y as row-column
  on:rc+/:{x,reverse each x} -1 1,'0; // orthogonal neighbours of rc
  nn:on where all flip[on]within'0,'s-1; // near neighbours: eliminate out of range
  s sv/:nn }
```

```
q)h[2 3;4]
1 3 5
q)h[2 3;2]
5 1
```

Note that this can easily be adapted to diagonal neighbours instead of or as well as orthogonal neighbours; also to vector `y`.

Key concepts

- Use [`sv`](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/sv) and [`vs`](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/vs) to encode/decode numbers to any arithmetical base
- Use of [map iterators](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/maps) Each and Each Right to control iteration

Comment: `h` retrieves only the /closest/ orthogonal neighbours -- not /all/ cells on the row and column: e.g. `h[3 4;6]` misses out the cell on position `4`.
but the `s vs i` idiom is very inspiring and i've come up with this: 
`f:{x sv/:raze flip each L:2 cut ({(x;til[y]_x)}./:flip (x vs y;x))'[0 1 0 1;0 1 1 0]}`
e.g. `4 5 7 2 10~f[3 4;6]`

Comment: Ouch. No, you didn’t ask for neighbours. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if your approach works in the general case? It may only work for your specific setup, e.g.

```
q)A:3 cut neg[6]?20
q)A
12 13 4
7  9  17

q)f[A;9]
12 7
```

One alternative approach is to use `in` to find the columns and rows to include

```
f2:{except[raze(x where y in'x),f where y in'f:flip x;y]}

q)f2[A;9]
7 17 13
```

Comment: granted, "my" `A` is expected to be containing cell indices/positions, not cell values, and the expected result should be the "neighbouring" cell ids/positions